# JSHint and JSCS inline ignore for the same next line

Tags: javascript, jshint, jscs

Is it possible to somehow make JSHint and JSCS play along nicely on inline ignore for the same next line?

I would like to do something like:

```
/* jshint camelcase: false, jscs requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers: false */
```

I tried a couple of different variations of that (separate "comment blocks", semi-colon in between, different lines for ignore), but couldn't make it work. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious? Or is it simply not possible? Thnx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSHint doesn't allow disabling a specific rule for a single line, but it is possible to disable all validations for a line:

```
var do_something; /* jshint ignore:line */
```

For JSCS, the syntax to enable/disable a single rule is like this:

```
// jscs:disable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
...
// jscs:enable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
```

Put together, to disable both JSHint and JSCS validation for a particular line, one would use a combination of the comments above:

```
// jscs:disable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
var var_name_with_underscores; /* jshint ignore:line */
// jscs:enable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
```

If the non-camelcase identifier is used in multiple lines inside a block (as is normally the rule), it may be necessary to enclose the whole function in comments.

```
// jscs: disable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
/* jshint ignore:start */
function foo()
{
    var var_name_with_underscores;
    ...
    var_name_with_underscores = 123;
    ...
}
/* jshint ignore:end */
// jscs: enable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
```